# Datatable freezed header

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

Datatable fixed header when scrolling up and down like this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/dPixie/byB9d/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#student_datatable').DataTable( {
            fixedHeader: true,
            scrollX: true,
            bSort : false
        } );
    } );
```

**fixedHeader: true** is doesn't work. can you help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link to fiddle in your question has nothing to do with DataTables.
It uses some css to implement fixed header functionality for a regular html table. In your case this css is useless.

For DataTables use the [FixedHeader plugin](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/)

First of all you need to reference it by adding this to your html(in case that it is not already included):

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.1/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.1/css/fixedHeader.dataTables.min.css">
```

then

```
$('#student_datatable').DataTable({
    fixedHeader: true
});
```

will work as expected ([Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/byB9d/10263/))

Answer (score 1):

I had a few problems where the header moves about.

Use the `dataTables_scrollHead` class.

```
<table class="OTHER_CLASSES_HERE dataTables_scrollHead">
   ...
</table>
```

If you're having problems with datatables in modals (which I did), use the `.draw()` api when opening the modal.

Its easier to access the api like this when you have `retrieve: true` as a DT init obj option.

([ref](https://datatables.net/reference/option/retrieve)).

I hope this helps,

Rhys